# Using Mockito but getting null pointer exception when running the test case

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit, mockito

I am trying to make test cases junits for the function using selenium webelement as argument.

I am trying to mock the element but this test case is giving error. The method for which I am trying to make test case is this.

```
 @Override
    public boolean isDownloadStarted(WebDriver driver) {
        boolean isDownloadStarted = false;
        ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<>(driver.getWindowHandles());
        if (tabs.size() == 1) {
            isDownloadStarted = true;
        }
        return isDownloadStarted;
    }
```

The test case is which is giving null pointer exception

```
DownloadStatusListenerImpl status;

@Before
public void before() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    status = new DownloadStatusListenerImpl();
}
@Test
    public void testDownloadStatusListenerImpl() {
        Mockito.when(status.isDownloadStarted(Mockito.any(WebDriver.class))).thenReturn(true);
        assertEquals(true, status.isDownloadStarted(Mockito.any(WebDriver.class)));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't stubbing the `status`. You could either add a `@Spy` annotation to it (and stop overwriting it):

```
@Spy // Annotation added here
DownloadStatusListenerImpl status;

@Before
public void before() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    // Stopped overwriting status here
}
```

Or you could explicitly call `Mockito.spy`:

```
@Before
public void before() {
    status = Mockito.spy(new DownloadStatusListenerImpl());
}
```

**EDIT:**

Calling `when` on a method like this will still invoke it, and thus fail. You need to use the `doReturn` syntax instead:

```
Mockito.doReturn(true).when(status).isDownloadStarted(Mockito.any(WebDriver.class));
```

Comment: using Spy is also giving same error NullPointerException only.

Comment: @WhiteWalker Arg, my mockito-fu is out of practice. See my edited answer.

Comment: Same result null pointer exception even after using doReturn as you suggested.